# No module named 'rest_framework' on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, hosting, pythonanywhere, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to host my Django app on https://pythonanywhere.com

I'm am getting the following error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

I tried

```
pip install djangorestframework

pip3 install djangorestframework
```

but its is still showing error.

I also tried `pip freeze` and found `djangorestframework==3.13.1` in the list.

```
>>> import rest_framework
```

also works fine.

I ran my project locally and also it in a new virtual env, it worked fine. Installed same requirements.txt on pythonanywhere but still the same error.
This is bugging me for a long time! please help

here is my error log file:

```
2021-12-22 10:59:23,012: Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 167, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 290, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 556, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/shantanu2k21/ytPlaylist/ytPlaylist/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('',include('play.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/shantanu2k21/ytPlaylist/play/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/shantanu2k21/ytPlaylist/play/views.py", line 13, in <module>
    from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

Comment: In your error log...it's showing the error on `urls.py` file.

Comment: Did you add 'rest_framework' in your installed_apps inside your settings.py file?

Comment: If you're trying to use a virtualenv on PythonAnywhere, make sure that you've configured the website to use that virtualenv -- there's an option on the "Web" page to do that.

Comment: I did added it in the installed apps. I actually wasn't using any virtual environments. I tried again with a virtual env and it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not using a virtual environment but using one and configuring it worked.